# Get qt metaobject type name from template parameter

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

In qt it is possible to use the meta object system to get the type names of parameters of slots by calling `QMetaMethod::parameterTypes()`.
E.g. for `void someSlot(SomeClass c);` it returns `"SomeClass"`.

Is there a way to get the same type name from a template parameter?
I.e. I want to call `somehowGetName<SomeClass>()` and get `"SomeClass"` as result.

It is important, that the name returned is exactly the name that qt uses and that it works on all compilers. Thus parsing the output of `type_info::name()` is not a solution.

If at all possible macros should be avoided. Also note that `SomeClass` does not inherit `QObject`.

Thus what I am probably asking is, if there is a way to get qts internal name for a given type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried demangling the result of type_info::name():

```
inline QString demangle(const char *name)
{
#if (__GNUC__ && __cplusplus && __GNUC__ >= 3)

    int status = 0;
    QString result = "";

    char *realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status);
    realname == NULL ? result = name : result = realname;
    free(realname);

    return result;

#else

    return name;

#endif
}
```

Comment: As I said above: "parsing the output of type_info::name() is not a solution."

Comment: I think the above code possibly satisfies "It is important, that the name returned is exactly the name that qt uses and that it works on all compilers. " which is why I provided the possible solution. I think the short answer to your question is, no, but you could always patch Qt to provide the functionality your looking for, or simply use the same typename extraction logic that they are using. Since it's Qt, they likely are macroing out each compiler like I did above.